# 403 error with plesk and wordpress error forbidden

Tags: wordpress, plesk-onyx

i want to link my website to a woocomerce extension called shopmaster

but when insert my link and click on connect im getting this error i have tried everything

Forbidden
You do not have permission to access this document.
Web Server at shopalway.co.za

things i have tried!

1. making sure my post name is correct
2. enabled directory browsing
3. setting file and folder to 755 filezilla
4. i even created a folder called httacces
5. clearing coockies
6. contacting webhost they say nothing is wrong
7. made sure rest api is enabled
   8.deleted all files reinstalled wordpress
8. even changed the web.config file in code
   from false to true hope to let it make a difference

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />  (<---was on false)
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="400" />
      <error statusCode="400" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\bad_request.html" />
      <remove statusCode="407" />
      <error statusCode="407" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\proxy_authentication_required.html" />
      <remove statusCode="414" />
      <error statusCode="414" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\request-uri_too_long.html" />
      <remove statusCode="415" />
      <error statusCode="415" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\unsupported_media_type.html" />
      <remove statusCode="503" />
      <error statusCode="503" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\maintenance.html" />
      <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\unauthorized.html" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\forbidden.html" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\not_found.html" />
      <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\method_not_allowed.html" />
      <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\not_acceptable.html" />
      <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\precondition_failed.html" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\internal_server_error.html" />
      <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\not_implemented.html" />
      <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\Inetpub\vhosts\shopalway.co.za\error_docs\bad_gateway.html" />
    </httpErrors>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
   <rule name="WordPress: https://shopalway.co.za" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*" />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
   </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

i have installed ssl certificate let encrypt recently as well.

using plesk onyx17.8.11
windows shared hosting

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo3xb.jpg)
<--Click links for image errors

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV4sr.jpg)
<--Click links for image errors

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRDTf.jpg)
<--Click links for image errors

[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTues.jpg)
<--Click links for image errors

Answer (score -1):

Redirection issue:

https://shopalway.co.za/ is working
but the error is shown onely on http://shopalway.co.za/
* that mean that you have an **SSL**:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://shopalway.co.za/

**SOLUTION**: Add these lines on the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```